# Wordpress admin right sidebar isn't working

Tags: wp-admin

I don't what happened but few times ago its working and now i don't what i did so it stops working,

I want its quick fix,

Currently when we're adding new post it looks like that screenshot :

[image]

Column is already 2 and nothing changed when we use 1 column,
I want its right sidebar.

Comment: Uninstall plugins to see if it does not come from one of them. Also, update WordPress: 10 updates pending... + update to the latest WordPress version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this with an older version of WordPress. I have not seen it with more recent updates. You fix is to update, honestly. This should be the least of your reasons to do so.

Without updating, the only way I was able to sort it out was by editing the (if I remember correctly) `screen_layout_*` key values in the `*_usermeta` table using PhpMyAdmin, in my case. I should stress that that was a hack to get by until I updated. It isn't really a fix. *Caveat Emptor*.

Also, update.

Comment: i've wp 3.4.2 version already

Comment: That isn't what your screenshot says. Anyway, look for those values in the DB and try to get things to reset.

Comment: i've one more question if you can answer 
can i use spanish language in wp admin with english wp version
any plugin for it ?

Comment: This feature works beautifully on a 3.4.2 on a dev server I have. If it continues to lock up like that something there is a deeper problem.

Comment: @MohitBumb, I don't know about the spanish language plugin but that is a different question anyway.